# how to create a hyperlink that will only open in chrome and uses a disable flag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, hyperlink

I want to create a hyperlink that will open `chrome` by using flag `--disable-hang-monitor`. after than it should open website `https:\\randomwebsite.com`

google chrome location

```
c:\program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-hang-monitor
```

website

```
https:\\randomwebsite.com
```

I tried this but how to set flag & always open in chrome?

```
<a href="https:\\randomwebsite.com">Website</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to specify that link should be opened in chrome since html tag `<a>` doesn't support this functionality.
For more info please see the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp